# Unable to Power Arduino and DC Motors via 2 AAA Batteries

Tags: arduino, dc, dc-motor

I am using 3.7 V 2000mah battery.
I am stepping it up to power an arduino board via an NCP1402. It has a continuous output current of 200mA.
I am trying to run two Micro Metal Gear motors with stall current 700mA. This setup works fine.

However when I try to use 2 AAA batteries and power it up, it does not seem to run the motors.
Any idea why? Any ideas as to how to overcome this issue?
Thanks!

Comment: Maybe because 2 AAA batteries is only 2.4-3V?

Comment: This is the board I have used to step up to 5V - http://www.pololu.com/product/798

Comment: "but the regulator can provide up to 200 mA if the input voltage is high enough." You are running on reduced input voltage, and therefore it will be reduced current. Also, you should really have a power system that can provide the stall current at least.

Answer (score 3):

The problem seems to be you're trying to take out 2*700 * (5V/3V) = 2.33 A from the AAAs, which is problematic. Even more, the batteries have internal resistance (which lowers the 3V) and you have DC converter losses.

I guess a pair of good NiMHs might be capable of providing that current (I've seen 5A briefly), but then again, you're still massively out of spec of the components in your power system.